# cannot import cv on OpenCV2.1

Tags: python, opencv

I have downloaded OpenCV2.1 and Python2.6.

when i try to `import cv` using `sys.path.append("C:\OpenCV2.1\Python2.6\Lib\site-packages")` and  then `import cv`, it tells me `ImportError: DLLload failed.`.

I have tried the solutions given in previous thread to copy the two files in the above path to `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`, but i still can't `import cv`.

Is it because I missed out doing some steps after installing? What could be the reasons to why the system cannot find the module `cv`?

Comment: Are the opncv dll's on the path or somewhere that python can find

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCV DLLs seem not to be found. Did you add OpenCV's bin directory to your `PATH`, `"C:\OpenCV2.1\bin"` in your case?

---

To use the Python wrappers

```
sys.path.append("C:\OpenCV2.1\Python2.6\Lib\site-packages")
import cv
```

should work, as well as copying `cv.lib` and `cv.pyd` to your `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages` (assuming you installed Python to `C:\Python26`).

But those wrappers have to find the DLLs they should wrap. So make sure, they are in a path Python can find them.

Maybe this question [Installing OpenCV on Windows 7 for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709301/installing-opencv-on-windows-7-for-python-2-7) may help, especially [Gia Thuy's journal post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709301/installing-opencv-on-windows-7-for-python-2-7/5131442#5131442) he mentions in his answer. Although he uses Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.2, the procedure remains the same.