# Cannot import cv on Opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am using a Windows 10 machine and have installed Python, numpy and OpenCV from [the official link](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0) using pre built binaries. I can successfully import numpy and cv2 but get an error when I try to import cv.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np
import sys
import cv

def diceroll():
    rng = cv.RNG(np.random.randint(1,10000))
    print 'The outcome of the roll is:'
    print int(6*cv.RandReal(rng) + 1)
    return 

diceroll()
```

ImportError: No module named cv

P.S: This is not a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096064/cannot-import-cv-on-opencv2-1). The user in the question involved is getting a dll file error whereas I am stuck with an import error for cv.

Comment: There is no top level `cv` module. Remove the `import cv` statement and, wherever you where using `cv`, replace it with `cv2.cv`.

Comment: @Jaime : Thanks Jamie but it did not work for me. It prompts an 'AttributeError: module object has no attribute cv' for the line 'cv2.cv.RNG(np.random.randint(1,10000))'

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I think they changed the Python namespace in 3.0, so those functions are probably directly in `cv2` now. Does `cv2.RNG` work?

Comment: @Jaime : I am using version 3.0.0 of OpenCV. Nope, that too doesn't work for me. It says that the object has no attribute RNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inquiring on the OpenCV community, I learnt that **the old cv or cv2.cv api was removed entirely from OpenCV3**

One cannot use the RNG function from cv through opencv3. You can instead use numpy.random for the same functionality.

Reference: my [question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/69126/python-import-cv-error-on-opencv-300-no-error-for-import-cv2/) on Opencv community

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhere in there, just need to search for it. Try running something like the following on your system:

```
from types import ModuleType

def search_submodules(module, identifier):
    assert isinstance(module, ModuleType)
    ret = None
    for attr in dir(module):
        if attr == identifier:
            ret = '.'.join((module.__name__, attr))
            break
        else:
            submodule = getattr(module, attr)
            if isinstance(submodule, ModuleType):
                ret = search_submodules(submodule, identifier)
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cv2
    print cv2.__version__
    print search_submodules(cv2, 'RNG')
```

On my system, this prints:

```
2.4.11
cv2.cv.RNG
```

Comment: I get what you are doing :) . It prints 3.0.0 and searches for cv but is not able to find it. It ends up in a 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp'. Do I have to add some path or set environment variables? (I have not set any before and just followed the official link mentioned above.)

Comment: On my system, if I have it searching for something non-existing it returns `None` pretty quick, i.e. `search_submodules(cv2, 'i_dont_exist')`.