# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run a python Code. It imports cv, but when it tries to do so, the above error pops up.
The only function where cv is used is

```
cv.Moments(points)
```

cv2 imports just fine and I'm on python 3.7 version.
If anyone has a workaround for this specific problem? I'll be much obliged. Thank you!

Comment: `cv` appears to be an old version of the module, which you don't have installed (based on a FAQ at https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/). Import `cv2` and change `cv.Moments` to `cv2.Moments` (or its `cv2` equivalent).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import cv on Opencv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048313/cannot-import-cv-on-opencv2)

Comment: Do you really want to import Moments from cv ? Now it is replaced by cv2

Comment: yes, I really want cv.Moments() . I've tried cv2.Moments() . But it just throw some numpy error.