# Not able to import cv in python 2.7.10

Tags: python, computer-vision, windows-vista, opencv3.0

I am using Python 2.7.10 and opencv 3.0.0 on windows vista. I am able to import cv2 but not able to import cv. I am using

```
import cv2.cv
```

but it gives

```
ImportError: No module named cv
```

I have followed two questions [cannot import cv on OpenCV2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096064/cannot-import-cv-on-opencv2-1) related to it but even those are not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, `cv` was removed as of OpenCV 3.0

Comment: till which version of OpenCV it is available ?

Comment: I believe until 2.4.6 it was there. You should generally try to avoid using the cv api and switch to cv2.