# python wont load module unless started in a specific directory

Tags: python, opencv, ld, pythonpath

I just pulled the latest version of opencv from source, and unfortunately for the moment I must have 2 different versions on one machine.

So I have the default location  `/usr/local/...` for the older version, and a custom location for the newer version.

My issue is that if I open a python terminal and try to `import cv2`, I can only get the new version to load if I start in the `opencv/lib` directory of the new version.

I want to be able to toggle which version of opencv I use, ideally it would be in the python script itself.

I expected to be able to set either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` or both in the terminal, or change the environment variables using `os.environ`, but had no success.

First, I don't understand why I have to be in the `lib` directory to get the new version to load, and second I don't see why I cannot dynamically change where python looks to import the module using environment variables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10859845/1134940

Comment: Thanks I imagine the same technique will work for me even though I am working in Linux. The trick is that I might not want to overwrite the older version for now, so I wanted to be able to toggle within a script. `imp` did what I wanted but when I want to migrate for good I will try your technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `imp` module to import from a specified path.

```
import imp
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('cv2', ['/path/to/opencv/'])
cv2 = imp.load_module('cv2', fp, pathname, description)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html

Comment: sounds like this should do the trick. I will make sure and mark solved once I verify it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the sys module. After the Python interpreter is started, you can modify the module path via sys.path which is actually just a list.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/cv2")
```

Comment: Probably you'll need to put "path/to/cvs2" before the "/usr/local" in sys.path.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I tried to do both `sys.path.append(pathname)` and `sys.path.insert(0,pathname)` with no luck. This is why I am so puzzled as to _what_ exactly the problem is, and why this solution doesn't work.