# OpenCV don't show methods in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, opencv, pycharm

I'm trying to install the OpenCV library, to be able to manipulate images, to install it, I'm using the command in prompt:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

But it doesn't work, in pycharm the methods I need do not appear, such as: "cv2.imread()" or "cv2.imshow()":

[Pycharm IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tzcM.png)

Notes:

- I'm using the python version 3.11.1
- i'm using the OpenCv version 4.7.0.68
- I'm coding in Windows plataform

I also tried using the command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

I thought that would solve the situation, but it stayed the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix issue but roll you back to the previous version

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.62
```

do this to return back to the latest version

```
pip install -U opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

in PyCharm open from menue `FILE - SETTINGS` go to `PROJECT:<your_project_name>` and select `PYTHON INTERPRETER` click on the gear symbol next to the interpreter path and select `SHOW ALL` make sure the correct interpreter is selected click on that icon that looks like `a folder tree (on the top)` click on the `"+" icon` select the folder where the opencv package is located normally (if you installed it via package manager) you will find it in: `<your_project_path>\venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2` click OK (twice) wait for updating skeletons

Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411482/11687405