# My cv2 does not recognize the method detectMultiScale()

Tags: python, opencv, package, version

Hello everyone I am working on a project I have version 4.6 of opencv apparently does not detect this method.
As if it didn't exist, it doesn't return any error either.
I put an image. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkVxX.png)
if recognized, it would display the following [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVOgL.png)

it could be that something is not installed correctly or there is a problem with the version ?

[update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWeK2.png)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cv.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale()
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code IDE detects the methods and give some information about the parametrs in this case says Any like not exist Regards.

Comment: If you have installation issues please try a fresh virtual environment! If you need more help please add details to your question like IDE (e.g. VSCode), installer (e.g. pip), package info (e.g. from pip list) etc. to your question. Read [ask]. Additionally please check this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html#gsc.tab=0) how to use `CascadeClassifier`.

Comment: Hello, I have the suspicion that it may be some error because of the way to install it, I am using visual studio code . I installed it using pip install opencv-python I have tried version 4.7 and I get the same error. In the documentation indicates that these methods exist in these versions so I think that is the way to install it is not done correctly. But other things in opencv let me use them, so it's weird.

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment for your project? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Hi @Markus I have tried to use pycharm and I get this error  Cannot find reference 'CascadeClassifier' in module __init__.py and in Visual Studio Code  find the reference but the method is missing i upload an updated image

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment for your project? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Additionally please be aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73551085/18667225