# Pycharm doesn't recognize cv2 modules

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

i am using python 3.10.5:

In pycharm, when importing cv2, all modules work, but only show
.bootstrap(),
.collect_extra_submodules() and
.load_extra_py_code_for_module
But when entering old projects, all prompts are displayed normally

Comment: needs debugging details. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm does not recognize cv2 as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34365044/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56 --force
```