# Import cv2: ImportError: DLL load failed: windows 7 Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit) Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, opencv, dll

I am using Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit) Python 3.6.0 on windows 7. I am getting the error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." for importing the package import cv2.

I have downloaded the OpenCV package and copy paste cv2.pyd into the Anaconda site package and updated my system path to point to OpenCV bin path to get the DLL. Still I am not able resolve this issue.

I did another way to install using pip install opencv-python. Still  not working.

Please need suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Try this command on the anaconda command prompt `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0 `

Comment: Thank you Jeru Luke. I was able to resolve this issue by a alternate way  Windows-only .whl pip install OpenCV 3 which was suggested at the site (https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/)

Comment: tky for mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

use python 2.7.1.0 instead of python 3, cv2 worked and dll load error fixed after using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473737/2924323) and install [official](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) or [unofficial](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) versions of `opencv` into your system. The problem you are getting is a problem with the `Anaconda`. Issue is also posted in [github](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue- However open cv was running fine, after installing some other packages and updating I got the DLL load failed when I tried to import cv2

I fixed this by typing in the conda prompt:

```
pip intall opencv-contrib-python
```