# Python OpenCV PyCharm Autocomplete

Tags: python, opencv, autocomplete, pycharm

Hey guys I am using PyCharm to code in python.

Python Version: 3.6.1
CV2 Version: 3.2.0

When I import cv2 with "import cv2" the autocomplete in PyCharm is broken. There are no suggestions with `cv2.` -->
When I'm writing `cv2.cv2.` --> then I get the right suggestions but the code does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete for OpenCV-Python in Windows not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672087/autocomplete-for-opencv-python-in-windows-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm Opencv - autocomplete with import cv2.cv2, no errors with import cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659906/pycharm-opencv-autocomplete-with-import-cv2-cv2-no-errors-with-import-cv2)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import cv2.cv2 as cv2
```

That solved the problem for me

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This did not work for me. I've answered how I solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190224/opencv-built-from-source-pycharm-doesnt-get-autocomplete-information/61281004#61281004

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this before.

1. find "cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd" in "Lib\site-packages\cv2" path. ("site-packages" path can be found by "pip --version")
2. Copy it to "DLLs" path. ("DLLs" path is located at "Lib\site-packages....\DLLs")

Work for system python and anaconda environments(need to do this in conda envs path)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69849595/19541435) to an answer post that works for me.
(credit to @dxl. Kindly upvote his/her post if it works for you. I did it too)

In short, I just added another interpreter path in my python interpreter settings that points to:

```
<my full path to venv>/Lib/site-package/cv2
```

The steps are:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Go to: Settings -> Project -> Python interpreter |
| 2. | Click on the "gear symbol" and select "Show All...". This will navigate you to a "Python Interpreters" window. |
| 3. | While your intended interpreter is highlighted, click on the "path symbol" which will navigate you to an "Interpreter Paths" window. |
| 4. | Click "+" symbol to add path in the interpreter paths window. |
| 5. | Add a new interpreter path as shown above. |
| 6. | In my case, I needed to restart my PyCharm IDE for the autocompletion to finally work. |

As opposed to his/her configurations, my configurations are:

|  |
| --- |
| - *PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1 on Windows 10* |
| - *Python 3.9.10 running in a Virtual Environment (Virtualenv)* |
| - *opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66 installed in the virtual environment via pip command* |

Answer (score 0):

In the lower right corner PyCharm
[image: 1]

Show All...
[image: 2]

Show path for the selected interpreter
[image: 3]

Add -> /lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2 -> OK -> Apply
[image: 4]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).