# PyCharm OpenCV- autocomplete with import cv2.cv2, no errors with import cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm just getting started with PyCharm, python, and OpenCV, and I'm trying to set up my environment. I've installed all the necessary packages and I import OpenCV like so:

```
import cv2
```

However, this does not autocomplete and shows warnings that the method may be missing when called, BUT if I import like so:

```py
import cv2.cv2
```

autocomplete *does* work, but running produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dunnj/PycharmProjects/TransformApps/transformapps/blackwhite.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2.cv2 as cv2
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv2'
```

Comment: try to look in the site-packages and look at the cv2 location you will find your answer.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I'm afraid I don't understand... cv2.pyd is located in site-packages/cv2; it's `__init__.py` is at the same level as matplotlib, and yet matplotlib auto completes... cv2.py appears to be a file that pycharm has decompiled... if that is the case, how can I get pycharm to autocomplete anyway?

Comment: opencv runs on python bindings and complied from cpp sources and they might not correctly autocomplete in pycharm

Comment: @ArpitSolanki but they *can* autocomplete, as evidence by autocomplete working when `cv2.cv2` is imported, so is their any way to get this actually working?

Comment: Be aware that there is bug in the current``opencv` package - see stackoverflow.com/a/76110480/11473934

Answer (score 22):

My Configuration:

- PyCharm 2021.2.3 on macOS 11.6
- Python 3.9.7 running in a Virtual Environment(VE)
- opencv-python 4.5.4.58 installed into the VE via pip using the PyCharm Terminal window

Steps that worked for me to get autocompletion working:

**tldr**: Update python interpreter settings to point to `<full path to venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2`

1. In preferences, Select Python Interpreter
2. Click the setting icon ( gear on right of box that display your Python Interpreter and select Show All
3. A list of all your configured Interpreters is show with your current interpreter already hi-lighted.
4. With your interpreter still highlighted, click the Icon that shows a folder and subfolder at the top. Tool tip should say "Show Paths for Selected Interpreter.
5. Click the + button and add the following path:
   `<full path to the venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2`
   The .../python3.9... will be different if you are using a different Python Version.
6. Click Ok until you are back to the main IDE window.

This has worked in three different Virtual environments for me so far. For two of those, I had to restart the IDE for the completions to show up. The remaining one did not require a restart and worked immediately.

Comment: Worked with opencv 4.5.4.60. Thank you very much

Comment: This is the correct solution! Works and doesn't need any code changes (import workarounds etc.). Thanks you

Comment: Great. Totally worked for opencv-4.7.

Comment: BTW, this can also PARTLY solve tensorflow keras autocompletion problem. I still cannot use `from tensorflow.keras import xxx`, but `from tensorflow import keras` will work and everything in keras can be autocompleted. Saved me for tf envs with versions >= 2.6.

Answer (score 17):

Credit to **ingolemo** from [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5r3wt4/in_pycharm_i_have_to_import_a_module_as/ddh8slf/). I was stuck on this for ages and it drove me mad so I'm here sharing.

My OpenCV was installed by using the wrapper [opencv-python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python)

---

> The sys.modules hacking that that module is doing is the source of the
>   problem. Pycharm doesn't exactly import modules in order to know
>   what's inside of them, so messing with the imports dynamically like
>   that confuses pycharm greatly. It's not pycharm's fault, the
>   opencv-python maintainer should have used a star import rather than
>   that messy import hack. You should be able to work around the problem
>   using the technique you stumbled upon. All you have to do is catch and
>   ignore the error under normal operation:

```
import cv2

# this is just to unconfuse pycharm
try:
    from cv2 import cv2
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. One note when working in project with multiple files you always need to import it like that, otherwise there will be errors.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I could import cv2 and have the program run but without autocomplete or use the try-except block but with execution error.
I solved this way:

1. Select project interpreter
2. Click on the settings button next to it and then clicking on the Show paths for selected interpreter
3. adding the directory containing the .so cv2 library (in my case in the Conda Python library path - e.g. miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/python-3.7). In general check the site-packages/cv2/python-X.X directory)

Answer (score 8):

just execute the following commands in your project working environment.

1. `pip uninstall opencv-python`
2. `pip install opencv-python==4.5.4.60`

Comment: This one solved my problem in latest pycharm

Answer (score 4):

The proposed import solution did not work for me.
I had exactly this problem with OpenCV 4.2.0 compiled from sources, installed in my Conda environment and PyCharm 2020.1.

I solved this way:

1. Select project interpreter
2. Click on the settings button next to it and then clicking on the Show paths for selected interpreter
3. added the directory containing the cv2 library (in my case in the Conda Python library path - e.g. miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/python-3.7). In general check the site-packages/cv2/python-X.X directory)

Answer (score 3):

Following Workaround 2 from the JetBrains issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54649) helped me:

1. In PyCharm open from menue FILE - SETTINGS
2. Go to PROJECT:<your_project_name> and select PYTHON INTERPRETER
3. Click on the gear symbol next to the interpreter path and select SHOW ALL.
   Make sure the correct interpreter is selected.
4. Click on that icon that looks like a folder tree (on the top)
5. Click on the "+" icon
6. Select the folder where the opencv package is located
   normally (if you installed it via package manager) you will find it in:
   <your_project_path>\venv\Lib\site-packages\cv2
7. Click OK (twice)
8. Wait for updating skeletons

Comment: I'm on the latest version of pycharm and opencv on an apple m1. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Jedi solved this problem for me. 
You can use `pip install jedi` in terminal

You can find more info about jedi here: https://pypi.org/project/jedi/

Comment: On pypi they do not list pycharm as supported IDE. There is a "and many more". In my opinion the bottom line is: no support nor tutorials on how to deal with pycharm. Can you point us to an example where jedi is installed on pycharm and provides opencv autocompletion?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
i used

```
import cv2 as cv2
```

and after that both importing meth

Answer (score 0):

try

```
try:
     import cv2.__init__ as cv2
 except ImportError:
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv, then mark the virtualenv directory as excluded in your project structure in Pycharm project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this before.

1. find "cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd" in "Lib\site-packages\cv2" path.
2. Copy it to "DLLs" path.

Work for system python and anaconda environments(need to do this in conda envs path)

PS.

1. "site-packages" path can be found by "pip --version"
2. "DLLs" path is located at "Lib\site-packages....\DLLs"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved with opencv-python==4.8.0.76 version

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation about **why** it does so.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does, but the fact is that after I upgraded the package the issue was solved