# python wont let me import functions from the package opencv. "Cannot find reference 'VideoCapture' in '__init__.py'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, opencv

i have tried reinstalling opencv andimporting cv2 as `from cv2 import cv2` and all other solutions listed  here[1]: [Python 3 Opencv set up problem: "cannot find reference 'VideoCapture' in __init__.py" on Pycharm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229392/python-3-opencv-set-up-problem-cannot-find-reference-videocapture-in-init). other functions like cv2.imwrite and cv2.destroyAllWindows. i am open to solutions to this problem or alternative packages

```
import cv2
import os
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("C:example.mp4")
try:
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')
currentframe = 0
while (True):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print('Creating...' + name)
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
        currentframe += 1
    else:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code is supposed to grab frames from a video and save them to individual files. if someone has a solution to my problem or an alternative way of getting frames from a video without using opencv i would really apreciate it