# Cannot find reference 'imread' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, pycharm

hope you are doing good. I have been working on a project and I have this warning. So, please help me with this.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('img1.jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
```

this is the code

Comment: you might have named a directory in your project `cv2` (so it's trying to read from that, rather than the real `cv2` import)

Comment: message vs code does not make sense.  more details needed.

Comment: If you have Pycharm IDE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229392/python-3-opencv-set-up-problem-cannot-find-reference-videocapture-in-init

Comment: Can you show a complete stack trace please? Important information will be found in there to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, there appear to be multiple packages providing `cv2`. Can you show how you installed it? Make sure you are installing the version whose documentation you are using!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The code works fine on my system, the most likely explanation is a clash between the library and a `cv2` folder in the same directory as the script you are running it in. Whenever you import a module in Python, the first place it looks for the module is in the folder the script is running in. Also try updating the module via the command `pip install opencv-python --upgrade`.