# Pycharm "Cannot find reference" when OpenCV is in a venv python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, python-venv

**EDIT- Things I tried**

*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229392/python-3-opencv-set-up-problem-cannot-find-reference-videocapture-in-init) question is the same, but the solutions there did not solve my problem. I didn't have a DLLs folder so I made one, tried both with and without deleting the file in site-packages/cv2/

*I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669767/pycharm-can%C2%B4t-find-reference-of-any-opencv-function-in-init-py) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190224/opencv-built-from-source-pycharm-doesnt-get-autocomplete-information) and couldn't make it work.

*I also tried to delete `opencv-python` from my base interpreter and only download it on the venv, but still didn't work.

*I also tried to invalidate cache/ restart multiple times.

*I also tried to delete python and pycharm completely. When I upgraded to 3.10 I couldn't even install opencv. When I tried 3.8 again the same problem accoured.

---

I wanted to download ML libraries to Pycharm (python 3.8). Initially I just added them (e.g. `opencv-python`) in the python interpreter itself (Settings > Project > Python interpreter) and it worked fine (So now my regular interpreter has a bunch of libraries on it).

Then I read it's better practice to make a new venv and download the libraries there. I created a new environment:[image]

Then I entered the new interpreter and added `opencv-python` (plus sign > searched for this > Install package):
[image]

After that I made a short script that needs `cv2`. Pycharm couldn't import cv2, but the script runs correctly (displays the image) when "run" is pressed.

[image]

If I switch interpreter to the regular one it recognizes the cv2 methods and autocomplete me.

Comment: could please add the terminal screenshot of PyCharm?

Comment: @Sabil I can, but it doesn't print an error message. After running the terminal is empty, and after I press a button it exists with code of 0.

Comment: does any of this help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+cv2+cannot+find+reference

Comment: The only requirement for the library to be recognized is correctly setting the default interpreter for the project in settings. You've only already done that so it should work. Since the code works at run-time it's obviously the IDE file that indexes the venv's that needs refreshing - Try to clear the cache! If you run this in the terminal remember the venv needs to be activated, if you're using run configurations you'll also have to choose the right venv. But the warning in the editor window is only connected to the interpreter chosen in the settings.

Comment: @bad_coder I invalidated the cache and restart multiple times. I run via the run button on top right, and in my run configurations I chose the right venv.

Comment: @bad_coder unfortunately it doesn't, I'm trying the other threads Christoph suggested now

Comment: @benjamin if you did invalidate the cache the other possible explanation is that the stub files are missing from the package as you installed it. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192749) might work for you. The way [opencv is organized](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) can be rather complicated. It seems you need to manually set the windows DLL on the path after installation. See [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8822335) for some extra context about the other answer.

Comment: may I recommend adding those thoughts also to the other question that this question is marked a duplicate of?

Comment: @bad_coder I tried it now, but it didn't work (I didn't have a DLLs folder so I made one, tried both with and without deleting the file in `site-packages/cv2/`)

Comment: @benjamin I think you solved it. When you say at the bottom of the thread: *"If I switch interpreter to the regular one it recognizes the cv2 methods and autocomplete me."* that's it.

Comment: @bad_coder I thought you need venvs just so you don't end up downloading all your packages to the same interpreter. That's true? If so, then I wanted a new interpreter for a new venv, and in there I downloaded opencv for example. 
I mean- I know I have a working interpreter right now, but it supposedly bad practice to use it.

Comment: @benjamin yes you are supposed to use venvs. If you want edit the question to include the steps you have taken that didn't work for you, with links to the other answers you've tried. I get the impression you are using the venv. (Did you actually install packages -opencv- to the Python base installation? Because if you did that's wrong and might be the source of the error. Start from a clean Python base installation, create the venv like you showed, install opencv and it should work).

Comment: @bad_coder I deleted `opencv-python` from my base interpreter and made a new venv with it.  Then I downloaded `opencv-python` to the venv interpreter. Didn't work (also added it to the thread)

Comment: @benjamin I would advise starting from a clean Python base installation. Removing packages should be done [also using pip](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip). If you simply delete you can miss some files and subsequent errors can be hard to diagnose. (Always start with a clean base installation and don't change it). Anyway, I'm casting a reopen vote. (Also unselect the "make available to all projects" and "inherit site packages" in the 1st screenshot).

Comment: @bad_coder What do you mean by "starting from a clean Python base installation"? Deleting python itself and downloading again?

Comment: @benjamin you don't have to delete the current Python, just make a new installation in a different directory (that's how you can have several Python's on the system at the same time). You can try it without having to bother with setting the environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `anaconda`.

The first time I tried it didn't work, so it's probably a problem with having non-ascii username ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478719/11865149)). I had the `.conda` folder in a path which contained non-ascii, as well as the anaconda3 itself installed in a different place

To install it correctly:

1. Uninstall both anaconda, pycharm (uninstall other pythons if you have them).

**2. Create a new user with ascii only (e.g. Ben).
In this user:**

3. Install anaconda (I guess miniconda will work too)
4. Create a venv (I used [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/manage-your-python-virtual-environment-with-conda-a0d2934d5195) tutorials)
5. Install your packages using `conda-forge` like in the tutorials