# Kivy Camera as KV language widget

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, kivy-language

I am using Kivy with a webcam. I have followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294385/python-kivy-camera-widget-error-with-opencv) by @Arnav of using opencv to form and display the camera as a widget. I have "extended" the layout within python it to add two buttons as a test, in preparation for a more complicated layout.

```
class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30,resolution=(1920,1080))
        root = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        root.add_widget(self.my_camera,1)
        box2 = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
        btn2 = Button(text='Hello world 2')
        box2.add_widget(btn1)
        box2.add_widget(btn2)
        root.add_widget(box2, 0)
        return root
        #return Builder.load_string(kv)
```

While this works I would prefer to move the UI components out of python and into a `kv language` file.
The problem is knowing how to "describe" the `self.my_camera` in the `kv` file?

I am not sure whether to inherit the `KivyCamera` class as a `widget` within the `kv` file i.e.

```
kv = '''
<Cam1@KivyCamera>:
    texture: self.my_camera
    resolution: (1920, 1080)
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
```

Or whether to use the `canvas` widget

```
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: self.my_camera
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

I have tried other "hacked" implementations, but in all cases the problem is linking through the `self.my_camera` into the `kv` file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this example may help you.

```
# Import 'kivy.core.text' must be called in entry point script
# before import of cv2 to initialize Kivy's text provider.
# This fixes crash on app exit.

import kivy.core.text
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window


class KivyCamera(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = None

    def start(self, capture, fps=30):
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule_interval(self.update)
        self.capture = None

    def update(self, dt):
        return_value, frame = self.capture.read()
        if return_value:
            texture = self.texture
            w, h = frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]
            if not texture or texture.width != w or texture.height != h:
                self.texture = texture = Texture.create(size=(w, h))
                texture.flip_vertical()
            texture.blit_buffer(frame.tobytes(), colorfmt='bgr')
            self.canvas.ask_update()


capture = None


class QrtestHome(BoxLayout):

    def init_qrtest(self):
        pass

    def dostart(self, *largs):
        global capture
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.ids.qrcam.start(capture)

    def doexit(self):
        global capture
        if capture != None:
            capture.release()
            capture = None
        EventLoop.close()


class qrtestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (.4,.4,.4,1)
        Window.size = (400, 300)
        homeWin = QrtestHome()
        homeWin.init_qrtest()
        return homeWin

    def on_stop(self):
        global capture
        if capture:
            capture.release()
            capture = None

qrtestApp().run()
```

and the kv file:

```
<QrtestHome>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            height: 20
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'Testing the camera'

        KivyCamera:
            id: qrcam

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            height: 20
            size_hint_y: None

            Button:
                id: butt_start
                size_hint: 0.5,1
                text: "start"
                on_press: root.dostart()

            Button:
                id: butt_exit
                text: "quit"
                size_hint: 0.5,1
                on_press: root.doexit()
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, however, it just produces a light grey screen with nothing else. Assuming this is from `Window.clearcolor = (.4,.4,.4,1)`

Comment: This is probably caused by the filenames of your. py and .kv files. Just name these qrtest.py and qrtest.kv. And try again.

Comment: That works! Although after sometime I am getting a memory exception. `[WARNING] [GL          ] BGRA texture support is not available
 Exception Exception: Exception('Unable to allocate memory for texture (size is 921600)',) in 'kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.allocate' ignored` should I raise another question?

Comment: I have had it running for 30 mins without any issues. So can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please could you tick the answer if it was the answer you were looking for?